# ¿Evitar relacionar a la misma persona con el mismo grupo mas de una vez usando ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Dado el siguiente codigo:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Activo")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        
class Person(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(Base):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

¿Cómo puedo restringir que el modelo permita registrar mas de una vez la misma persona en el mismo grupo?

Por ejemplo en el administrador de Django registro dos instancias de `Person`: `AAA` y `BBB`; y dos instancias de `Gruop`: `XXX` y `YYY` y me permite registrar dos instancias con valores iguales iguales de `Membership`, es decir, la combinación (`AAA`, `XXX`) dos veces.

NOTA: La clase Base se utiliza en otros modelos, por lo que si la solución implica modificar esa clase, afectaría a los demás.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a esto está muy bien documentada en la sección de [Constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#module-django.db.models.constraints) de Django, específicamente en el apartado de [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint).

Anteriormente, se hubiese hecho uso de la opción `unique_together` de la clase `Meta`, pero como bien indica [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together), esta es una manera que pronto se considerará obsoleta.

Por lo tanto, lo que tienes que hacer es algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
class Membership(Base):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['person', 'group'],
                name='unique_person_per_group'
            )
        ]
```

Si intentas ahora guardar un par repetido de `person`-`group`, se lavantará una excepción de tipo `IntegrityError` (la cual puedes importar de `django.db.utils`). Por lo tanto, ten en cuenta manejarla apropiadamente en tu código.